# Select all records from specified day

Tags: sql, date

I have table named `table_food` in db with columns: `first name`, `last name`, `date`, `food name`. I want a query that returns all food names from specified date.

For example my table records looks like:

```
John Watson   2016-08-22   steak
John Watson   2016-08-22   burger
John Watson   2016-08-23   fries
John Watson   2016-08-23   apple
```

and I want to get all food names from 2016-08-23. How should I create my query?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE date = '2016-08-23'`.

Comment: SELECT food from table_food WHERE date = '<DATE_HERE>'

Comment: thanks, going to try

Comment: Plz try first before ask questions.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the database you use.
I added also a distinct because I imagine that you need only distinct values of food names.

For MySql

```
 select distinct(food_name) from table_food 
 where date = '2016-08-23'
```

For Oracle

```
select distinct(food_name) from table_food 
where date = to_date('2016-08-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Check for dialects of other databases.

Note that if the data stored in the date column has also hours, minutes and seconds you need a different query to extract data, for example in oracle:

```
select distinct(food_name) from table_food 
where trunc(date) = to_date('2016-08-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m just assuming you´re using a MySQL-Database. The answer may vary for other databases.

There are two versions, depending on what you´re trying to get.

If you just want a list of all foods, including duplicates, you could use:

```
select food_name from table_food where date = '2016-08-23'
```

If you just need to get distinct values (each food name once) you could use:

```
select distinct(food_name) from table_food where date = '2016-08-23'
```

The first question could be: Which meals have been served and how many of them?
The second question could be: Which meals have been served at all (no matter how often)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "2016-08-23";
SELECT * FROM `table_food` WHERE `date` = '{$date}';
```

The reason I'd variable the date is solely down to as and when you wish to change the date. Don't get me wrong either of the above you can do. My personal preference would be to adjust the variable rather than the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to retrieve data from a table, you'll have to specify what field you need to select from what table, under one or several conditions.

Since your condition is the date, 
we'll use this syntax:
We added the word distinct in case you didn't need redundancy.

```
Select distinct FoodName 
from Table_Food
Where date = '2016-08-23'
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.